# Module augmentation is not working in .vue file

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, typescript-typings

there is a module augmentation (**types/test.d.ts**):

```
import Vue from 'vue'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $test: string
  }
}
```

And include it as (**tsconfig.json**):

```
// ...
"include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx",
    "types/*.d.ts"
  ],
// ...
```

And then, it works fine in any **.ts** file:

[image]
[image]

But it just gets a compile error in **.vue** file
[image]

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add types/*.d.ts to typeRoots in yout tsconfig

Like this:

```
"typeRoots": [
        "src/types"
    ],
```

(Normally I use @types to store my .d.ts files)